# NodeJs SQLite query returns other values than direct SQL on database

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm a bit puzzled by the situation I have now.

I've a simple SQL statement I execute from NodeJs on a SQLite database. The SQL statement returns values with a lot of decimals; although my data only contain two decimals.

When I run the exact same query in DB Browser for SQLite, I have a correct result.

My NodeJs code

```
app.get('/payerComparison/', (req, res) => {    
    // Returns labels and values within response
    var response = {};

    let db = new sqlite3.Database('./Spending.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY, (err) => {
        if(err){console.log(err.message); return}       
    });

    response['labels'] = [];
    response['data'] = [];
    
    db.each("SELECT payer, sum(amount) AS sum FROM tickets GROUP BY payer", (err, row) => {
        if(err){console.log(err.message); return}

        response['labels'].push(row.payer);
        response['data'].push(row.sum);
    });

    db.close((err) => {
        if(err){console.log(err.message); return}
        // Send data
        console.log(response);
    
        res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
})
```

What I have in the command line

```
{
  labels: [ 'Aurélien', 'Commun', 'GFIS', 'Pauline' ],
  data: [ 124128.26, 136426.43000000008, 5512.180000000001, 39666.93 ]
}
```

The result in DB Browser

[image: Printscreen of query results in DB Browser]

I hope you can help me clarify this mystery!
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Round the values up to 2 decimals :).

```
SELECT payer, round(sum(amount),2) AS sum FROM tickets GROUP BY payer
```

Comment: It does the job, thank you. Though I still doens't understand where does the difference come from.